# Reloading jQuery Smooth Zoom Pan viewer after resizing container

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

I am developing an image viewer which is responsive and have chosen to use Smooth Zoom Pan plugin to get the desired pan/zoom functionality.

I have 2 main panels, the viewer container and a controls container which sit side-by-side using the Bootstrap 3 grid system.

The controls container needs to be collapsable (nicely) to allow the viewer to stretch to fill the screen. In order to do this I've used jQuery animation and set widths to the parent containers, which works ok.

What I'm trying to find out is, how do I make the Smooth Zoom Pan viewer match the parent container width? This is what I have currently but when the viewer is resized I loose the pan/zoom functionality.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="viewer-container">
                <div class="viewer-content">
                    <img src="/images/site/your_image.jpg" border="0" id="yourImageID" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="controls-content">
                <h2>Currently viewing:</h2>
                <p class="time">12:00</p>
                <p class="date">Thursday 19th July 2016</p>
                <div id="viewerCalendar"></div>
                    <a class="btn primary btn-block"><span class="icon-spinner11"></span>Get latest images</a>
                    <a class="btn primary btn-block"><span class="icon-lock"></span>Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="close-tab">
                 <a class="btn primary tab" id="close-controls">close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#close-controls').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("closed");
        var controlsContent = $('.controls-content');
        var viewerContainer = $('.viewer-container');
        if (controlsContent.is(':visible')) {
            controlsContent.slideToggle('slow', function () {
                viewerContainer.parent().css('width', '100%');
                viewerContainer.animate({
                    width:'100%'
                }, "slow", function () {
                    $('#yourImageID').smoothZoom('resize', {
                        width: '100%'
                    });
                });
            });
        } else {
            viewerContainer.animate({
                width: '75%'
            }, "slow", function () {
                viewerContainer.parent().css('width','75%');
                viewerContainer.css('width','100%');
                controlsContent.slideToggle('slow');
                $('#yourImageID').smoothZoom('resize', {
                    width: '100%'
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I'm new to asking questions on here so if you need anymore information in order to help me out please comment below and I'll do my best to get you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself in the end, instead of resizing the image to `width: '100%'` I had to get the width of the viewer's container and set this width on the resize like so:

```
var viewerWidth = $('.viewer-content').width();
viewer.smoothZoom( 'resize', {
    width: viewerWidth
});
```

Side note: I also swapped out my jQuery animation for moving the panels off screen to the built in Bootstrap off screen functionality and just altered it to work for all screen sizes. I'm unsure to whether this had some effect on the final solution working as I wanted it to.